# Advise on running a python script cron ... switching source environments

Tags: python, cron, virtualenv, environment

I need to run a cron job server side to access and retrieve some data from an API endpoint...

I'm just looking for advise on switching virtual python environments.

Would something like this:

```
0 4 0 0 0 cd to/python/root/environment/path && source activate myenvironment && cd && path/to/python path/to/my/python/script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
0 4 0 0 0 to/python/root/environment/path/bin/python path/to/my/python/script
```

I.e. it's enough to run the script with `python` from the virtual environment.

Comment: Excellent - will try this. Also, are we able to run crons outside of the root user?

Comment: Of course, but that user has to have access to the virtualenv, i.e. the venv should not be in /root. Recreate it in /usr/local, /var or /home/$USER. Recreate, don't move — virtual environments aren't relocatable.